# Hover over opacity

Tags: html, css

Just wondering, will it be possible to change the opacity of a particular div class and other div classes when we hover over that particular div class? If so, how do I do it? Any comments will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you please mention any screenshot for better understanding or explain little more.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just take a tutorial online.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. An example is the website http://minimalmonkey.com/. Look at how the other divs darken when it is not being hovered over to.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after!

```css
    div {
      height: 50px;  
    }
    
    .divOne {
      background-color: purple;
    }
    
    .divOne:hover{
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    .divTwo {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .divTwo:hover{
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="divOne">
    
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
    
    </div>
    <div class="divOne">
    
    </div>
```

See the working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/19r6nvz7/1/

Here are some resources for researching this further:

**:hover** - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

**opacity** - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of hover opacity.. one is the div opacity and the other is background opacity.. 
    1: for div opacity , its also effect the content visibility 
     as :

```
 #div1:hover{
       opacity:0.5;
    }
```

2: for div background opacity , its only effect on the background and we can use RGBA for this.
    as :

```
#div1:hover{
       background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
.first{
  background-color:red;
  height:500px;
}
.second{
  background-color:green
}
.third{
  background-color:tomato
}
.first:hover{
  opacity : 0.7
}
.second:hover{
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
.third:hover{
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 first"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 second"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 third"></div>
</div>
```